# MySQL Foreign key created although its reference does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> INSERT INTO ENROLLMENT (ssn, courseNumber, quarter, grade) 
VALUES ('333333333', '124', 'Fall2012', 'C');

mysql> select * from section;
+--------------+------------+------------+------------------+
| CourseNumber | Quarter    | RoomNumber | DayTime          |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------------+
| 100          | Fall2012   | 5          | MW 1:00-2:OOPM   |
| 100          | Fall2013   | 5          | MW 1:00-2:OOPM   |
| 124          | Fall2013   | 5          | TuTh 3:00-4:OOPM |
| 124          | Spring2011 | 36         | Tu 5:30-8:OOPM   |
| 220          | Winter2014 | 450        | MWF 8:30-10:OOAM |
| 220          | Winter2015 | 450        | MWF 8:30-10:AM   |
| 233          | Fall2013   | 210        | Tu 1:00-3:00PM   |
| 233          | Summer013  | 210        | Tu 1:00-3:00PM   |
| 233          | Summer2010 | 200        | MW 1:OO-2:OOPM   |
| 266          | Summer2013 | 300        | Tu 1:00-3:00PM   |
| 266          | Summer2014 | 300        | Tu 5:00-6:00PM   |
| 266          | Winter2011 | 121        | TuTh 7:30-8:OOPM |
| 400          | Spring2010 | 330        | TuTh 2:00-3:00PM |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------------+


| ENROLLMENT | CREATE TABLE `ENROLLMENT` (
  `SSN` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `CourseNumber` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `Quarter` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Grade` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SSN`,`CourseNumber`,`Quarter`),
  KEY `CourseNumber` (`CourseNumber`),
  KEY `Quarter` (`Quarter`),
  CONSTRAINT `enrollment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SSN`) REFERENCES `Student` (`SSN`),
  CONSTRAINT `enrollment_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`CourseNumber`) REFERENCES `Course` (`CourseNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `enrollment_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`Quarter`) REFERENCES `section` (`Quarter`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

I am a beginner in SQL. I am learning basic SQL queries.
In Section table, course number 124 with Fall2012 does not exist. Yet, I was able to create it. How is it possible?

Comment: If i understand correctly, then there is another table which contains `(course_number, quarter)`, and there is no `(124, Fall2012)` there?
Well, you did create individual (single) Foreign Key constraints. So both 123 and Fall2012 do exist independently from each other. What you probably want is, a constraint on both: `CONSTRAINT fk_course_quarter FOREIGN KEY (course, quarter) REFERENCES table_course_quarter (course, quarter)`. You might then need a (unique) index on `table_course_quarter (course, quarter)`. Is that what you are looking for? Can i make this an answer?

Comment: Yes, I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible because `CourseNumber` 124 does exist.  And, Quarter `Fall2012` exist.

From your question, I think you want a compound foreign key reference:

```
CONSTRAINT `enrollment_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (CourseNumber, `Quarter`) REFERENCES `section` (CourseNumber, `Quarter`)
```

You may need an appropriate index or unique constraint on `section` for the declaration to work.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, a smarter `section` table might look like this:

```
+--------------+------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+----------+
| CourseNumber | Year | Quarter | RoomNumber | WeekDays | StartTime | EndTime  |
+--------------+------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+----------+
|          100 | 2012 |       3 |          5 |        5 |  13:00:00 | 14:00:00 |
|          100 | 2013 |       3 |          5 |        5 |  13:00:00 | 14:00:00 |
|          124 | 2013 |       3 |          5 |       10 |  15:00:00 | 16:00:00 |
|          124 | 2011 |       1 |         36 |        2 |  17:30:00 | 20:00:00 |
|          220 | 2014 |       4 |        450 |       21 |   8:30:00 | 10:00:00 |
|          220 | 2015 |       4 |        450 |       21 |   8:30:00 | 10:00:00 |
|          233 | 2013 |       3 |        210 |        2 |  13:00:00 | 15:00:00 |
|          233 | 2013 |       2 |        210 |        2 |  13:00:00 | 15:00:00 |
|          233 | 2010 |       2 |        200 |        4 |  13:00:00 | 14:00:00 |
|          266 | 2013 |       2 |        300 |        2 |  13:00:00 | 15:00:00 |
|          266 | 2014 |       2 |        300 |        2 |  17:00:00 | 18:00:00 |
|          266 | 2011 |       4 |        121 |       10 |  19:30:00 | 20:00:00 |
|          400 | 2010 |       1 |        330 |       10 |  14:00:00 | 15:00:00 |
+--------------+------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+----------+
```